# How to consume java webservice in C

Tags: c

My project has a requirement where I have to develop a C component which consumes java web service. This C module has to be integrated again with Unsion (which has unify as the language). I am new to both of these things and not sure where to start.

Can someone help me by pointing to some libraries or anything which helps in calling java webservice in C.

Thanks,
sveerap

Answer (score 0):

Use a [SOAP library for C](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=SOAP+library+in+C).

Comment: Thanks, I will try to look into this. But are there any specific librarys which I can try out with. I could find something like gSoap on net but any idea will it suitable for requirement.

Comment: One of the feedback I got is to use http://ws.apache.org/axis2/c/index.html . I will have to evaluate this one too